# Task, Back Button, and onSaveInstanceSate method

Tags: android, android-activity, task

Hello I am just a little confused after reading these materials on [Tasks and Back Stack](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/tasks-and-back-stack.html), Android Developer Guide:

It says:

> When Activity A starts Activity B, Activity A is stopped, but the system retains its state (such as scroll position and text entered into forms). If the user presses the Back button while in Activity B, Activity A resumes with its state restored.

While in [the APIs reference for onSaveInstanceState() method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onSaveInstanceState%28android.os.Bundle%29), it says:

> One example of when onPause() and onStop() is called and not this method is when a user navigates back from activity B to activity A: there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState(Bundle) on B because that particular instance will never be restored, so the system avoids calling it.

The above two situations seem identical to me ("press the `Back` button to Activity A" and "navigate back from Activity B to Activity A"). But I don't understand why while the former says Activity A resumes with its previous state restored while the latter says the particular instance of Activity B will never be restored. Any explanations?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the first one is saying that A will be saved so it can be restored, and the second one is saying that B will not be saved because it can't be restored.

Comment: You are right, the second is saying the B (not A) will not be restored (I missed reading it)! When pressed Back button from B to A, B is destroyed, and A is restored, so there is no need to call onSaveInstanceState() on B. Am I right?

Comment: correct, but as a practical matter, it's a good idea always to be prepared for a call to onSaveInstanceState in your activity because you never know what will happen -- a notification might catch the user's eye and they do something, then return to B from that other activity, and then B would need to be restored.

Comment: "When the user presses the Back button, the current activity is destroyed and the previous activity resumes."

Comment: Thanks, sometimes for a newbie it is just very easy to get lost when reading the developer guide!

Comment: just keep in mind that another activity can come along via notification and when they press Back from that activity, your activity (B, for example) is then restored